# Prevent Cmake to add preferred path in qmldir

Tags: qt, cmake, qml

I use Cmake for a Qt/QML project with only qml files where there are not compiled and not added to the Qt resources.
The command qt_add_qml_module() create the qmldir but add a preferred path to the Qt resources so the Qt engine cannot find qml files.

How to prevent cmake te add this line in the qmldir

I tried to remove this line with option of the qt_add_qml_module() but with no result.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I have a problem where `prefer` prevents my singletons from working and I'm getting very desperate.

Comment: I prevented CMake to generate the qmldir with the qt_qml_add_module and create my own function to generate it without the prefer

Answer (score 0):

Add `qt_policy(SET QTP0001 OLD)` to your CMAKE file to use the old resource prefix mode where the default prefix is ":/". But attention: this is a deprecated setting, you should use this carefully.

[QTP0001](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt-cmake-policy-qtp0001.html)

Comment: Set the QTP001 policy to old juste change the default prefix but don't prevent CMake to add the prefer path in the qmldir, so the QML engine continue to search files in the resources